# Command to unlock "Locked" files on macOS Sonoma

Tags: macos, filesystems, read-only, plist, macos-sonoma

In the end I manage to delete a `.plist` file from MacOS Sonoma recovery but when I reboot it keeps appearing again.

Why does this happen and how do I solve it to eliminate it permanently?

```
chflags nouchg,noschg /file
rm -f /file
```

It is the file that controls the performance and cycles of the battery, the battery still works and is within its cycles but, when I disconnect from the power, the performance and the mouse and everything else decrease. Whatever you do lags. I don't remember in which version of MacOS I was able to delete it without problems and it worked, it no longer lost performance or became slow with the mouse or lag even if it was not connected to the power.

So since they made the system volume read-only I have never did. Could you delete that file? Until today, after a tutorial here I was able to delete it from recovery but I already tried several times and it appears again when the machine is turned on. In recovery mode I manage to mount the volume with edit permission (without the read-only message) but it is of no use if the file appears again when restarting.

Comment: What exactly is the file (i.e. its full path)? Are you sure you're deleting the right file in recovery (the filesystem is arranged rather differently there)?